# PyroCMS - Add WYSIWYG editor in frontend

Tags: wysiwyg, pyrocms

i need to show a simple editor in the frontend of my website.
I tried to append the wysiwyg editor in my Public_Controller in this way:

```
function ask(){
    $this->template
                ->title('ask your question')
                ->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', $this->data, TRUE))
                ->build('user/ask');
}
```

but when i tri to see my frontend page i get this error:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to locate the file: fragments/wysiwyg.php
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way. In the controller `$this->template->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', $this->data, TRUE));` while in the view just use `wysiwyg-advanced`

Comment: How did you solved it? still not working for me. Did you change or copy to different location?

Comment: No, just add that code in my controller, if you open a topic on pyrocms forum I can help you there posting some code

Comment: Thanks! It's there :) https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/25593/how-to-add-wysiwyg-in-front-end-module